# Sql Server select with regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database, subquery

can we use regular expression to select the item from database?
The table item is like below

```
Table column|name|
10.01.02    | a  |
100.2.03    | b  |
1021.10.04  | c  |
```

Now my problem is that i need to select the column and get the substring like below

```
Table column|name|
10.01       | a  |
100.2       | b  |
1021.10     | c  |
```

any suggestion with regular  expression or substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column1,0,(CHARINDEX('.',column1,CHARINDEX('.',column1)+1))) 
FROM Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc9ee/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
select left(a, datalength(a) - charindex('.', reverse(a))), b
from (
    select '10.01.02', 'a' union all
    select '100.2.03', 'b' union all
    select '1021.10.04', 'c'
) t(a,b)
```

I think there is no solution with regexp.

**UPD**

Another solution:

```
select reverse(parsename(reverse(a), 1)) + '.' + reverse(parsename(reverse(a), 2)), b
from (
    select '10.01.02', 'a' union all
    select '100.2.03', 'b' union all
    select '1021.10.04', 'c'
) t(a,b)
```

Comment: what if there are more items in table column

Comment: You didn't say that you need to leave only two first sections instead of deleting the last one. See another solution. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There may simple smarter way. But this is what i can think of.

```
select substr(column, 1,lenght(column)-instr(reverse(column),'.'), name from table;
```

Comment: My apologies. I didnt notice, it is for sql server. I misread mssql as mysql.